# Word for people who easily believe in rumors, and for a person who spreads them

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Basically, I am asking for two words-

1. What do we call a person who spreads rumor?

And on the flip side, there will always be some people who easily believe rumors.

2. What do we call people who believe in rumours?

Is there a word, or phrase for both types of people?

Comment: A *rumour-monger*, *gullible* and *credulous*, perhaps?

Comment: @Mick sound like an answer to me. Even more accurate then exciting answer.

Comment: @sumelic almost a perfect duplicate were it not for "and on the other side there are few people who believe....is there any word for them?" bit. So the OP is asking for at least two separate but related answers. Is that on topic?

Comment: @passa You see if you ask for a **word**, users will think you want one word, but you really want TWO *words*, one for the "gossipers", and one for those who are willing to listen and even more ready to believe. It's not possible to have a single word for someone who spreads gossip and believes in the gossip they spread. Are you asking that?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: That's true; I figured I'd await clarification from passa to learn if the answers there are satisfying. I think Brian Hooper's answer provides a word (if an obscure, archaic word) that fits both sides; it says "Merriam-Webster suggests *quidnunc* is more likely to be someone keen on hearing the latest gossip than repeating it".

Comment: @sumelic too late now. it's been closed as a duplicate, and passa seems to be a drive-by user. My DV was for the question being *unclear* in case someone is wondering.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Actually i asked two questions in one. word for who spreads rumor and word for people who believe in it.Basically two different word. Maybe it's too late too clarify.

Comment: @passa: If you want to get the question reopened, it is not too late. You could edit it to make it clearer, and then people like Mari-Lou A who found it too unclear might vote to reopen. But if you already have found an answer that satisfies you at the linked post, then it is most appropriate to leave this question marked as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @sumelic i think the edit clarifies that this question is not a duplicate, and I've voted to reopen. If you feel you can improve the edit further, hop on board.

Comment: I forgot about my dupehammer! I have the "power" to reopen SWR :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[*Rumour-monger*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rumour-monger), [*gullible*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gullible), and [*credulous*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/credulous) are all possibilities:

> **rumour-monger** - noun [ C ]  ​
>
> a person who spreads rumours
>
> **gullible** - adjective
> ​
> easily deceived or tricked, and too willing to believe everything that other people say
>
> **credulous** - adjective [formal]
> ​
> too willing to believe what you are told and so easily deceived

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: You forgot "sucker" and "sap", but earned another +1, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are describing a **gossiper**.

According to Vocabulary.com:

"A gossiper is someone who talks eagerly and casually about other people. If you like to spread rumors and hear the latest news about your friends, you might be a gossiper. When you gossip, you talk enthusiastically about other people's news or business. To do this regularly is to be a gossiper."

Comment: okay but what about them who believe in it?